# How to fix the python codes to extract full links from a webpage? Available codes extracted partial links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner with python and using BeautifulSoup to extract links from the following webpage https://mhealthfairview.org/locations/m-health-fairview-st-johns-hospital. All available codes are like the follows,

```
html_page = urllib.request.urlopen("https://mhealthfairview.org/locations/m-health-fairview-st-johns-hospital"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

The outputs include partial links, such as "/providers", etc. It should be "https://mhealthfairview.org/providers". Is there any way I can extract the full link rather than the partial link? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`urllib.parse.urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin)

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = "https://mhealthfairview.org/locations/m-health-fairview-st-johns-hospital"
html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(urljoin(url, link.get('href')))
```

Comment: Thank you. It works.  I saved the outputs into a txt file because I need to use them for further extraction. It may not be a smart solution.                                                            for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    out=urljoin(url, link.get('href'))
    with open('1.txt','a+') as file_object:
        file_object.seek(0)
        data = file_object.read(100)
        if len(data) > 0 :
            file_object.write("\n")
        file_object.write(out)                If there is a better solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use an if.

```
webroot = 'https://mhealthfairview.org'
href = link.get('href')
if href[0] == "/":
 print(webroot + href)
```